# IWD Checkout extension not working in proto theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I have installed IWD Checkout M2 extension version 3.2.0 in proto theme, its giving few of errors in console please refer below screenshot and any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Issue fixed now i have copied all module view files under /app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/IWD_Opc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a file or two. Specifically `iwdOpcHelper.js`